# Laravel sync on other column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot

I've made a poll. A poll has options and an option has votes.

When someone votes I'm store it in the db like this:

```
public function store(Option $option)
{
    $option->votes()->sync([Auth::user()->id]);
}
```

The pivot table looks like this:

```
id
option_id
user_id
```

How do I make sure that when a user already voted, and then votes for something else the other vote goes away?

The sync method is only looking for the id.

Comment: The sync method as you called it will do exactly what you need. It will look for pivot table columns that have `user_id == Auth::user()->id` AND `option_id == $option->id`. So it should be fine.

Comment: @devk you are right! Thanks bit confused sorry about that. But any idea how I could make sure that a user can only vote once for a poll?

Comment: I'm not sure how your database is set up (I assume options belong to poll in some way, not sure if through many to many or one to many). One way would be to have a pivot between poll and user. If the pivot exists, the user voted on the poll (cant anymore), if it doesn't the user can vote. But depending on your design, you might have better options

Comment: I am not sure that the sync function will be enough for what he wants to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do:

The Database:

```
Poll
- name

Option
- value
- poll_id

Vote
- poll_id
- option_id
- user_id
```

The relationships:

```
class Poll extends Model 
{
    public function options () 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Option::class);
    }

    public function votes () 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vote::class);
    }
}

class Option extends Model
{
    public function poll ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Poll::class);
    }
}

class Vote extends Model
{
    public function poll ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Poll::class);
    }

    public function option ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Option::class);
    }

    public function user ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function votes ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vote::class);
    }
}
```

The code to avoid that a user can vote for multiple options:

```
// We first remove any eventually vote from this user on this poll
$user->votes()->where('poll_id',$poll->id)->delete();

// We then create a vote for the user
$user->votes()->create([
    'poll_id' => $poll->id,
    'option_id' => $option->id
]);
```

This will allow you more flexibility. You could, for example with this code, create a `hasManyThrough` relationship between a user and a poll through a vote to list all the polls of a certain user

Comment: Thanks for your time! I had a pivot table without the poll_id added that now. And it's a lot cleaner thanks!